# TYPO3: Deactivation of Backend Layout on specific page ID

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templating

Is it possible to deactivate a backend layout on a specific page ID ?
My backend layouts are connected to the frontend. Via page properties editors can choose the desired one. On a specific page this should not be possible. There should be just one option available.

Someone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with page TSconfig you can exclude some layouts from selection:

```
options.backendLayout.exclude = 1,2
```

but you have to consider:

you normaly have the field `backend_layout_next_level` and so you need a value in `backend_layout`.
be sure to set it and remove the option to empty it.
this can be done with removing the field from editable fields

```
TCEFORM.pages.backend_layout.disabled = 1
```

then you do not need to reduce the selectable options.

if editors should be able to edit the (backend) layout for subpages the disabling must be active only on the special page. You can use conditions:

```
[page|uid = 123]
TCEFORM.pages.backend_layout.disabled = 1
[global]
```

Comment: With this its even possible to exclude backend_layouts for certain user_groups. That's nice. Thanx!